# Can MD cope with a badblock list?

Tags: linux, mdadm, badblocks

I have a MD drive set in RAID6 configuration with LVM2 on top. One of my drives was faulted last night due to bad blocks. Now apart from the fact that I am aware I should physically replace the drive, I am wondering:

Can I feed MD a list of badblocks (such as I can with mke2fs -l [badblockslist]) in such a way that the these blocks are no longer used and effectively extend the life of the disk?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you can't.  You should also check the drive's SMART status either with the gnome disk utility or with `smartctl` from the smartmontools package.  If it is only a few bad sectors, md should have tried to rewrite them, which should have triggered the drive to automatically remap them to the spare pool.  If you have enough bad sectors that the spare pool has run out, then you need to replace the drive immediately.

Comment: Actually, Linux 3.1 added bad block management in mdadm. So you can now. But I'm upvoting anyway, for the good advice on checking the disk status and getting them remapped.